# How to invoke Plesk Git extension webhook via cURL from Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: git, bitbucket, plesk, bitbucket-pipelines

Unfortunately, Bitbucket doesn't support per-branch webhooks and won't support them in the near future (https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11728/trigger-webhook-only-for-push-to-specific).

So I thought I maybe could write a simple `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` which calls the corresponding webhook:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          script:
            - curl $WEBHOOK_STAGING
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - curl $WEBHOOK_PRODUCTION
```

Simply requesting the webhook, doesn't seem to trigger a `git pull` within Plesk, so I'm assuming that I need to add a payload.

**Question:** What do I need to send to the Plesk webhook in order to perform a pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhooks are done via a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request, so you will have to pass the argument `-X POST` to curl in order to send the request to your webhook correctly.

So your curl statement would look like this:

```
curl -X POST $WEBHOOK_PRODUCTION
```